# Could not connect smtp server on port 25

Tags: windows-7, smtp

I'm using a windows 7 PC

When I try to test an smtp connection through telnet giving the command:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

It shows a message:

```
could not establish connection to host, on port 25: connection failed"
```

How do I get my PC to establish a connection with the smtp host on port 25?

I checked the possibility of a Firewall blocking the port and also try using the telnet command on ports 465 or 587.

Comment: Some ISPs (such as my home one) block port 25 connections to any smtp server other than their own as an anti-spam measure. Even if your firewall allows it, the ISP's won't.

Comment: @Marc: great minds think alike! I swear, I started composing my answer before your comment was posted...

Comment: Why the hack put it -1 , i asked the problem i am facing. Is it poor quality content or someone lost his mind !

Comment: this is offtopic here. And you keep posting offtopic questions.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.  Perhaps your ISP has a policy of blocking outbound port 25 connections, except to their official outgoing SMTP servers.  That's why many services support
alternate port numbers for their SMTP service.  You didn't say what the results were
for the alternate ports, so it's hard to say for sure whether that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. The solution works for me

Either off the firewall OR Follow the below steps:

1. Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
2. Open Inbound Rules New Rule
3. Choose Port type
4. Choose TCP, and enter the required port - in our case, 25
5. Choose to Allow the connection Choose all three profiles (Domain+Private+Public)
6. Enter a custom rule name, e.g. "Port 25"
7. Press finish

Check whether SMTP port 25 is opened or not

```
    a. Open up a command prompt.
    b. Type “telnet <server_ip> 25” then hit enter.
    c. Once you are determined the results. Type quit and hit enter
```

**Important:** Antivirus software can help protect your computer against viruses and other security threats. In most cases, you shouldn't disable your antivirus software. If you have to temporarily disable it to install other software, you should re-enable it as soon as you're done. If you're connected to the Internet or a network while your antivirus software is disabled, your computer is vulnerable to attacks.

1. Click Start, Programs, McAfee, VirusScan Console.
2. Double-click Access Protection
3. select Anti-virus Standard Protection
4. Unchecked enable access