# Could not connect to SMTP host: {remote-server}, port: {port}, response: -1

Tags: java, email, exception, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using java mail api. But exception is come to me with above 
message.

> Could not connect to SMTP host: {remote-server}, port: {port}, response: -1

What`s mean **"response : -1"**

I can`t found this code in api manual.

Comment: Which API do you use - maybe you can show some code?

Comment: Please post what you tried. Is it really writing `{remote-server}` in the exception message? How did you specify the server and the port?

Comment: Yes I`ve fill out specify ip and port such as 127.0.0.1, 25

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158951/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-p

Answer (score 5):

A response code of `-1` means that JavaMail failed to get a valid response code from the SMTP server. You can view the relevant source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.mail/mail/1.4.1/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java#1577).

Most likely, you either have your properties set incorrectly or you have a networking issue such as a firewall blocking the connection.

You might try enabling debug mode (`session.setDebug(true)`). Please post your code if you need further help.