# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158951/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-p)

I tried to send an email through a jsp page but it shows the following error:

> `javax.mail.MessagingException`: Could not connect to SMTP host: www.gmail.com, port: 25, response: 421

This is the code I'm using to send the email:

```
<%
    try
    {
        String host = "www.gmail.com";
        String to = request.getParameter("to");
        String from = request.getParameter("from");
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String messageText = request.getParameter("body");
        boolean sessionDebug = false;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.host", host);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(messageText);

        Transport.send(msg);
        out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
        out.println(" from " + from);
        out.println(" using host " + host + ".");
    }
    catch (MessagingException mex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error: unable to send message....");
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

Could someone tell me what is causing this error?

Comment: [Quoting IETF - RFC 2821](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2821/): `421: <domain> Service not available, closing transmission channel`

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to the gmail mail server, not the web server.

So change

```
String host = "www.gmail.com";
```

to

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

EDIT: You'll also need: `String port = "587";` instead of `...port = "25"`