# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.yahoo.com, port: 25

Tags: jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158951/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-p)

I am trying to implement mailing facility in my code but I am getting this exception. Please suggest some solution. I am doing it in intellij idea.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.yahoo.com, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at SendMail.send(SendMail.java:53)
at SendMailTest.main(SendMailTest.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the exception because host smtp.yahoo.com is not responding on port 25 (most likely this port is permanently blocked on their firewall). Try another SMTP server (or your localhost).

Comment: can you suggest any other SMTP server. and if i am using localhost then can u put some code here so i will understand.thanx in advance

Comment: For development purposes, it's usually easier to install SMTP server locally. If you're on Windows, you can use SMTP service that comes with IIS, on linux I'd suggest using Postfix (http://www.postfix.org/). Once you have SMTP service up and running, just use localhost instead of smtp.yahoo.com in your configuration settings.

Answer (score -1):

I think that `smtp.yahoo.com` is an invalid smtp string. Try the valid smtp strings on this site:

- http://www.electrasoft.com/faq/faq32be.htm