# Connection timed out to host Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp

I have strange problem. I wrote method for sending email. Everything should be ok but still I'm getting the same error.

```
[http-nio-8081-exec-2] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:335)
    ...
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here is my config code:

```java
@Autowired
    JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendNewPasswordEmail(String firstName, String password, String email) {

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("noreply@baeldung.com");
        message.setTo(email);
        message.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
        message.setText("Hello " + firstName + ", \n \n Your new account password is: " + password + "\n \n The Support Team");
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
```

```java
@Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);
        mailSender.setUsername(USERNAME);
        mailSender.setPassword(PASSWORD);

        return mailSender;
    }
```

I tried different configurations and different dependencies. Strange thing is that earlier that worked about half year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158951/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-p)

Answer (score 0):

It says your application couldn't connect to the `smtp server`. There are many reasons for that, for example:

- Connecting to wrong URL or port.
- Your or their firewall is blocking the connection.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9962424/10109156).

Comment: I mean firewall in your server has to open the port (587) or url (smtp.mail.yahoo.com)