# Sending an mail in java using smtp

Tags: java

I am trying to send an email but i am getting following error:

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
nested exception is: 
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.17.1.65, port: 25
```

Comment: It's what the exception says: your mail server is not listening to port 25. Maybe you need to connect to a SMTPS port?

Comment: Does it seem similar to this problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158951/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-p

Answer (score 0):

test the netstat command first whether the host is responding or not. if it is yes then you need to check an email server/relay on host. you can test it by this link http://www.mailradar.com/openrelay/

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sharing a class for sending mail using Gmail SSL with multiple attachments.
Just change the gmailUsername and gmailPass with actual gmail credentials. And also change the to and from address with your desired one. 
Here we have used Gmail SSL smtp port for sending mail. You can change it with your own mailing server details.

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;

import javax.mail.internet.*;

import javax.activation.*;

/**

Author Mridul Chatterjee

 */

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

import javax.mail.Session;

import javax.mail.Transport;

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class SendMail {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put(”mail.smtp.host”, “smtp.gmail.com”);

props.put(”mail.smtp.socketFactory.port”, “465″);

props.put(”mail.smtp.socketFactory.class”,

“javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory”);

props.put(”mail.smtp.auth”, “true”);

props.put(”mail.smtp.port”, “465″);

ArrayList fileNames = new ArrayList();

fileNames.add(”C:/Write.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/Write1.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/Write2.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/Write3.txt”);

fileNames.add(”C:/25148.jpg”);



Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,

new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

return new PasswordAuthentication(”gmailUsername”,”gmailPass”);

}

});



try {



Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(”from@no-spam.com”));

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,

InternetAddress.parse(”tomail@mail.com”));

message.setSubject(”Testing Subject”);

message.setText(”Dear Mail Crawler,” +

“nn No spam to my email, please!”);

     //  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);



     //  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

    //   messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

    //   messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

       System.out.println(fileNames.size());

       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

       for(int i=0;i            {

                System.out.println(fileNames.get(i));





                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                DataSource source = new FileDataSource((String)fileNames.get(i));

                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

                messageBodyPart.setFileName((String)fileNames.get(i));

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                //message.setContent(multipart);

            }



       //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

       message.setContent(multipart);



Transport.send(message);



System.out.println(”Mail Sent Successfully….”);



} catch (MessagingException e) {

throw new RuntimeException(e);

}

}

}
```