# add footer/signature to mail in Java

Tags: java, email, mime4j

In one of my Java applications I have to forward e-mails. So, I get e-mails (plain text or multipart) with *any* content (maybe also attachments). I edit their subject, from- and to-header and send them via SMTP.

I already implemented this using [Apache James Mime4j](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/index.html) and [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html) but now I also have to append a footer/signature to the content of each e-mail.

Can I achieve this with Mime4j too? Would be great! How? If not: is there another way?

---

EDIT: Details after Wolfgang Fahl's comment:

Maybe I'm using the library the wrong way, but I am parsing the message as follows:

```
MessageBuilder messageBuilder = new DefaultMessageBuilder();
InputStream in = ...
Message m = messageBuilder.parseMessage(in);
```

Now I have an instance of Message and I can set it's subject, sender, etc. But [Message](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/dom/class-use/Message.html) does not provide a method `setText()` or something like that. Ok, there is `getBody()` but then I don't know how to manipulate the [Body](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/dom/Body.html).

Comment: Usually a footer is just part of the text of the message. So setText() would be your function. I assume you'd like to do something different - please explain what you are up to - may be with a code example.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I edited my question and added some details about my code. Basically I don't know what `setText()` method you mean.

Comment: I see what's going on. Personally I do not use James methods for sending mail by SMTP. I use javax.mail.Message. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358453/sending-an-mail-in-java-using-smtp for how to use it. You'll need to adapt from the james message to java's standard way on how to do things if you try this route.