# how to send email from our mail server in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is my code...

```
    final String from = "demo@ourmail.com";
    final String password = "demo1234";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "14.141.48.131");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        String subject = "Registeration conformation for happy shopping";
        String to = demo@gmail.com;
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent("<html>\n"
                + "<body>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<p> you are successsfully login</p>"

                + "</body>\n"
                + "</html>", "text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("end of utility");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

After running this, an exception is generated, i.e.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 14.141.48.131, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Please suggest how I can handle this exception.

Comment: Could you please check your SMTP connection using telnet to port 25 from your host?

Comment: If you are on a personnal internet connection, this is most likely that port 25 out is open only to send mails throught your ISP mail server. Try using port 465 or other secured port using SSL/TLS.

Comment: Please post the *entire* stack trace.

Comment: Your Java code looks fine.  Successfully communicating with your mail server is the hard part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158951/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-p)

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code looks fine. Successfully communicating with your mail server is the hard part.

*Maybe* you're running Java 7, and *maybe* (per [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/Mail+Server+Connection+Failed+With+%27java.net.SocketException%3A+Permission+denied%3A+connect.%27+Exception) link) the problem can be resolved by setting this simple JVM parameter: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

Definitely check your firewall (make sure the SMTP port is open between your Java program and the mail server), and definitely check for any anti-virus programs that might be restricting SMTP on the mail server.

Or maybe your mail server requires SSL/TLS encrypted SMTP port 465 (instead of SMTP port 25).

Then again, maybe your ISP/internet provider doesn't permit SMTP at all.

There are a million possibilities.  Talk with your network administrator.  And try these SMTP troubleshooting tips (independent of debugging your Java program):

- http://www.port25.com/how-to-check-an-smtp-connection-with-a-manual-telnet-session-2/

PS:

Never ever *EVER*!!!! post real usernames, passwords ... or IP addresses.  In *ANY* external forum.