# Getting javax.mail.MessagingException even when able to ftp/telnet the mail server

Tags: java, email

I am getting  the below given exception when I try to send mail from Unix.

> Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP
>   host: mailhost.fm.grp.net, port: 25, response: 554
>           ... 13 more

To check connection I did:

```
telnet mailhost.fm.rbsgrp.net 25 
  Trying 11.191.99.201... Connected to
 mailhost.fm.grp.net. Escape character is '^]'. 554
 lonix02002.fm.grp.net Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: are you sure sure with you connection port?

Comment: @AjayPandya it seems to work fine in different unix environment

Comment: hey this is one of the case where you need to set mail properties before you start sending mail or use SMTP

Comment: could you please post your code and look at this example http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/ I remember something like this had happened to me when I moved from one server to another.

Comment: @shruti hope you have read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7159065/3514144

Comment: Got my answer. The mailx server was not installed on this particular system, that was the reason for this error.